# Проект ASP.NET CORE Web API + ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, api, mvc

Ребятки, всем привет. Решил написать небольшой web api проект, который содержит серверную часть на web api и клиентскую на asp.net core. Но я совсем не могу понять с чего мне начать. Может кто помочь растолковать вообще что из себя это все представляет и направить в правильное русло?

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить коротко, то это технология, которая позволяет развёртывать веб-сайты любого масштаба, начиная с небольших сайтиков и заканчивая крупными порталами.

Могу предложить достаточно подробный и надёжный гайд по ASP.NET Core 5 + Web API, а также некоторым другим, связанным с ними направлениям — https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/. Там расписаны основные приёмы работы с .NET Core, его основные механики, а также механизмы создания, конфигурации, маршрутизации сайтов, наряду с Web API. Думаю, что с его помощью Вы можете узнать для себя много нового и полезного касательно .NET, Core и других ветвей :)